# How to count data for week with MYSQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I need to count the data in a mysql table for weeks, and if for a given week I have no data then the counter value must be equal to the value of previous week counter. Is there a query that will allow me to do this? I tried below Query

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(WEEK,tb.FirstDate,InfoData) AS Week,
       count(*) AS TOT
FROM MyTable,
  (SELECT InfoData AS FirstData
   FROM MyTable
   ORDER BY InfoTime LIMIT 1) tb
GROUP BY Week
```

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: I tried SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(WEEK,tb.FirstDate,InfoData) as Week,count(*) as TOT FROM MyTable,
(SELECT InfoData as FirstData FROM MyTable order by InfoTime limit 1) 
tb group by Week

Comment: But the above query count data only for the weeks in which there are data, to me instead serve every week and I have to return the previous count if for a given week, the count is 0.

Comment: Create a table `weeks` with the values you need, i.e. 0 to 1000 in the column `week_no` (nearly 20 years) and do a left join from this table to your select for a start.